# Error in .local(.Object, ...) : when working with RasterStack

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I am working with large multi-band raster images which, to avoid exceeding system memory, I am trying to process in blocks using the writeStart/writeValues function in the r raster package. I begin with RasterBricks, but after processing each band separately they become RasterStacks and I am unable to `writeStop` them, export them, or change them back to RasterBricks, and keep getting an `Error in .local(.Object, ...) :` error when I do.

Simplified code:

```
test = brick("raster.TIF")
out = brick(test)

out = writeStart(out,"test.tif", format = "GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
for(i in 1:test@file@nbands){
  tr = blockSize(test)
  for(j in 1:tr$n){
    x = getValues(test[[i]], row = tr$row[j], nrows = tr$nrows[j])
    x = x - min(x)
    out[[i]] = writeValues(out[[i]], x, tr$row[j])
  }
}
out = writeStop(out)
```

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeStop’ for signature ‘"RasterStack"’

```
out = brick(out)
```

> Error in .local(.Object, ...) :

So I am looking for any workaround or solution. `out = brick(out)` gives the `Error in .local(.Object, ...) :` error.

Comment: I don't see that line (giving the error) anywhere in your code?

Comment: sorry about that. Edited it to make it clear (hopefully).

Comment: don't know if it is your problem, but from the examples of the function it seems you should use  `getValuesBlock` and not `getValues` in the inner loop.  Not sure about the indexing you're using in writing, though. Could you post an example dataset (e.g., create a small brick to test on) ?